# Restart Resque-Pool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, init.d

None of [the signals](https://github.com/nevans/resque-pool), e.g. HUP, cause resque-pool to re-read the environment. So how can I script restarting?

In the init.d, I've tried "kill -QUIT" followed by starting it again:

```
echo "kill -QUIT $pid" | sudo -u deploy -i bash
echo 'cd /home/deploy ; bundle exec resque-pool --daemon --environment staging' | sudo -u deploy -i bash
```

...but I get an error:

```
/home/deploy/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/resque-pool-0.3.0/lib/resque/pool/cli.rb:62:in `manage_pidfile': Pidfile already exists at tmp/pids/resque-pool.pid and process is still running. (RuntimeError)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think since QUIT gracefully shuts down the workers and the pool manager you need to wait.  If you want to kill immediately, send TERM.

Comment: Thanks Tony. I'm not using resque anymore so can't verify. Will accept this if someone else verifies it.